# MPI error when running program after quitting it with Ctrl+C

Tags: c++, mpi

I have been running a program I developed in C++ with OpenMPI version 1.6.5 in Ubuntu 14.04.

Everything was working fine (i.e. the program was executing as it was supposed to) until I quit it using Ctrl+C at a point, as I realised I ran it with a wrong input value and could not be bothered to wait for it to complete (big, rookie mistake!).

After I changed the variable value and recompiled the program (allright), I tried to run the program again with `mpirun -np 8 program_name`. However, OpenMPI returned the following error:

```
mpirun has exited due to process rank 5 with PID 3363 on
node Hal exiting improperly. There are two reasons this could occur:

1. this process did not call "init" before exiting, but others in
the job did. This can cause a job to hang indefinitely while it waits
for all processes to call "init". By rule, if one process calls "init",
then ALL processes must call "init" prior to termination.

2. this process called "init", but exited without calling "finalize".
By rule, all processes that call "init" MUST call "finalize" prior to
exiting or it will be considered an "abnormal termination"

This may have caused other processes in the application to be
terminated by signals sent by mpirun (as reported here).
```

I tried to recompile the program and run it multiple times, but always got the same error with a different process rank depending on whichever was called first (I assume). Since I think the problem is relating to my "not so nice" way to quit the previous run, I restarted the computer, but the error is still there.

Is there a command to shut down all MPI runs or a file to clear to see if that was the problem?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: I'm inclined to think that this isn't related to how you exited the program earlier.  Can you run the program with mpirun -np 1, and then just run the program like ./program_name?  Do you get an abnormal termination?

Comment: You are right. I tried to run it with only one core as you suggested it works alright. I have just realised that the change in the parameter I made actually results in less runs and only 4 cores are sufficient to run the simulation.

Comment: If you want to post an answer where you explain that I made the mistake of running the program with an excessive number of cores I can vote for it.